# nagios 4.1.1 can't start in Centos 6.0

Tags: nagios

after runing:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 4.1.1
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-19-2015
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
Warning: use_embedded_perl_implicitly is deprecated and will be removed.
Warning: enable_embedded_perl is deprecated and will be removed.
Warning: p1_file is deprecated and will be removed.
Warning: sleep_time is deprecated and will be removed.
Warning: external_command_buffer_slots is deprecated and will be removed. All commands are always processed upon arrival
Warning: command_check_interval is deprecated and will be removed. Commands are always handled on arrival
   Read main config file okay...
Warning: failure_prediction_enabled is obsoleted and no longer has any effect in host type objects (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg', starting at line 52)
Warning: failure_prediction_enabled is obsoleted and no longer has any effect in service type objects (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg', starting at line 206)
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking objects...
        Checked 241 services.
        Checked 102 hosts.
        Checked 23 host groups.
        Checked 0 service groups.
        Checked 4 contacts.
        Checked 4 contact groups.
        Checked 37 commands.
        Checked 5 time periods.
        Checked 0 host escalations.
        Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
        Checked 102 hosts
        Checked 0 service dependencies
        Checked 0 host dependencies
        Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
```

This was upgrade from 3.5 to 4.1.1 which is almost new configuration with old commands that I used. Is there any trick in 4.1.1 ?

Comment: service nagios status shows no running

Comment: SELinux status?

Comment: Anything helpful in the logs? Sometimes the pre flight will tell you the config is fine, but won't pick up on permission errors or socket problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed nagios under /usr/local/nagios,
what does the nagios.log (/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log) say after you run service nagios start?

Comment: based on the lines:

Comment: [1459283041] Error: Module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o' is using an old or unspecified version of the event broker API.  Module will be unloaded.
[1459283041] Event broker module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o' deinitialized successfully.
[1459283041] Error: Failed to load module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o'.
[1459283041] Error: Module loading failed. Aborting.

Comment: the whole:[1459283041] 
[1459283041] Error: Module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o' is using an old or unspecified version of the event broker API.  Module will be unloaded.
[1459283041] Event broker module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o' deinitialized successfully.
[1459283041] Error: Failed to load module '/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o'.
[1459283041] Error: Module loading failed. Aborting.

Comment: pnp4nagios does not support collecting performance data via event broker yet.

https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/modes#bulk_mode_with_npcd_and_npcdmod

Attention Starting with Nagios 4 the internal structures have changed so the start of the module will fail. So far there are no plans to support Nagios 4. Please select any other of the modes.

Try using "Bulk Mode with NPCD" and restart nagios again.

Comment: I think this last lines in my nagios.cfg:

Comment: I think these lines of code in my nagios.cfg :

Comment: # PNP4NAGIOS
process_performance_data=1
broker_module=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/lib/npcdmod.o config_file=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/npcd.cfg

Comment: above lines of code makes the error :( are they important to keep them ?

Comment: You can delete it but you have to start up the npcd daemon to collect the performance data from Nagios.

Comment: You can refer to "Bulk Mode with NPCD" for nagios configuration

https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/config#bulk_mode_with_npcd

Comment: thank you, I have found this link with instructions so I will try to fallow up.

Comment: I have found this link  https://eagliponeo.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/how-to-install-pnp4nagios-using-bulk-modecentosrhelfedora/

Comment: I have found this link with instructions:  https://eagliponeo.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/how-to-install-pnp4nagios-using-bulk-modecentosrhelfedora/  - I think this is what I need  Thnak You so much for Your help

Comment: Cool. Good luck!